# Salesforce feature parameter

Tags: lmo, fma

I have Salesforce developer org connected with my LMO and I have enabled feature parameters in this developer org. I created all 25 features (LMO to Subscriber) and then deleted the unwanted ones. (This was to confirm if I am able to create all the 25). After deleting now the total number of feature parameters are 10. Now if I am trying to create a new parameter, 11th one it gives me this error:

You have exceeded your limit for the number of feature parameters (25).

And for the existing 10 features I am not able to edit any. It throws the same error. I checked in recycle bin there is no deleted records of feature parameter.

Comment: in the meantime -- worth upvoting https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EA0FQAW